# Como obtener los dos ultimos digitos de un numero en C

Tags: c

Tengo una variable que pide un número con un `scanf`

de este numero tengo que obtener los 2 últimos digitos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: `numero % 100`?

Comment: cómo se llama la variable?, podrías poner el código que llevas?

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar `%100` sobre el numero un ejemplo es este:

```
int numero=12343;
    int auxiliar;

    auxiliar=numero%100;
    printf("%d\n",auxiliar);
```

Comment: No sería necesario emplear otra variable. Con poner `printf("%d\n", numero%100);` es suficiente. No obstante, la solución que comentas es totalmente válida.

Comment: ya lo se ,lo he puesto porque imagino que en su programa tendrá el numero en una variable y querrá obtener el resultado en una variable para hacer algo con el. Solo he puesto el printf para que se vea que funciona bien. @Londo